# Returning text values from if statement which loops through rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, text

I want to create an if function that returns text values depending on the colour of rows in column D and the percentage in rows in column E.
E.g. depending on colour in D6 and value in E6, return a value in F6 and then loop through the rows repeating this.
The code I've written runs but no values are appearing anywhere on my excel sheet, can this be resolved?

```
Sub Message_Click()

Set shr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
shr.Range("F6:F37").ClearContents

Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D37")
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("E6:E37")

For RR = 1 To 33
Set rng2 = Cells(RR + 5, 3)
Set rng3 = Cells(RR + 5, 4)

If rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50 Then
    Range("F6:F37").Value = "Passed"
ElseIf rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 And rng3 > 60 Then
    Range("F6:F37").Value = "Warning"
ElseIf rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 And rng3 < 60 Then
    Range("F6:F37").Value = "Still has chances"
ElseIf rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 And rng3 = 100 Then
    Range("F6:F37").Value = "Failed"
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. This is because active workbook might not be the work you want to refer to at a given point. Always try an clearly qualify your workbook and worksheets. Don't use `ActiveSheet`.. instead qualify your sheet (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shee1")`)

Comment: Also what's RR? It hasn't been declared and you are missing an "=". It should be `For RR=1 to 33 ... Next RR`

Comment: Thank you the "=" was a typo error, RR is to loop through the rows and I didn't think I needed to define it, other codes I've written it didn't need to be defined (I have very little knowledge of using vba though)

Comment: Also, you might want to do your comparisons like that `rng3.value < 60`. Keep in mind that you are not performing cell-wise checks for the color index. So if one cell in `rng2` doesn't have a color index of 50, but all the others do, this `rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50` will return `FALSE`. So basically you are doing Range-wise checks. How do you want to do it? Cell-wise or Range-wise? RR doesn't have to be defined, but it's a bad practice if it's not.

Comment: You're approaching the problem backwards. Why not use conditional formatting to set the colour according to the value, rather than using VBA to set the value according to the colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compare the value of a range to a number, it should look like that:

```
rng3.value < 60
```

Also, keep in mind that you are not performing cell-wise checks for the color index. So if one cell in rng2 doesn't have a color index of 50, but all the others do, this:

```
 rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
```

will return `FALSE` for the entire range. So basically you are doing Range-wise checks.

As someone in the comments said, the logic is a bit backwards. However, here's one way  to do it:

```
Sub Message_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim RR As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
sht.Range("F6:F37").ClearContents
For RR = 6 To 37 Step 1
    If sht.Cells(RR, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 50 Then
        sht.Cells(RR, "F").Value = "Passed"
    ElseIf sht.Cells(RR, "D").Interior.ColorIndex= 38 And sht.Cells(RR, "E").Value > 60 And sht.Cells(RR, "E").Value < 100 Then
        sht.Cells(RR, "F").Value = "Warning"
    ElseIf sht.Cells(RR, "D").Interior.ColorIndex= 38 And sht.Cells(RR, "E").Value < 60 Then
        sht.Cells(RR, "F").Value = "Still has chances"
    ElseIf sht.Cells(RR, "D").Interior.ColorIndex= 38 And sht.Cells(RR, "E").Value = 100 Then
        sht.Cells(RR, "F").Value = "Failed"
    Else
        sht.Cells(RR, "F").Value = "N/A"
    End If
Next RR

End Sub
```

Here's the sample result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thats worked except for some reason the "Warning" message isn't working, instead anything that is color = 38 is coming back with the "Still has chances" message. This might be due to my logic, do you know if there is another way to get around this problem?

Comment: @cistrat so if the `.ColorIndex=38` and the value is 65 for example you're getting a "still has chances"??

Comment: Yes exactly! not sure why its happening

Comment: @cistrat It works fine for me.. I have updated my post with a sample result. Are you sure you copied and pasted the code correctly?

Comment: The code is exactly the same but mine is still coming up with all "still got chances" even if i change the order of the code

Comment: Solved! It wasn't excepting my numeric values as they were formatted to be percentages in excel but changed it and its worked.